# Sum certain values between rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of 370000 rows x 340 columns, in this DataFrame I have mixed numeric and non-numeric values between columns.

I'd like to merge rows, basing on `user_id`, that certain numeric values are summed, and non-numeric values are preserved.

Given table:

```
user_id          points    gender    age
11111              10000      male    18
 2222               4200    female    33
11111              30000      male    18
 2222                 10    female    33
11111              20000      male    18
```

I'd expect this result:

```
user_id          points    gender     age
11111              60000      male     18
2222                4210      female   33
```

While summing rows, I need to sum approx. 300 values out of 340, but I'm new to pandas struggling to find the right way to do this, would appreciate any tips.

Comment: I don't think it's numeric vs. non-numeric -- age is numeric, but you don't want to sum ages, right?

Comment: @DSM well yes, I'd like to merge only certain numeric values

Comment: you could do a `groupby` and then pick the aggregate function for each column. In this case something like `df.groupby('user_id').agg({'points':'sum', 'gender': 'first'})`

Answer (score 3):

You want to group your original `DataFrame` by `'user_id'`. Then you can aggregate the grouped frame and specify a dictionary for which function to use on each column.

```
df.groupby('user_id').agg({'points': 'sum', 
                           'gender': 'first', 
                           'age': 'first'}).reset_index()
```

Outputs:

```
   user_id  points  gender  age
0     2222    4210  female   33
1    11111   60000    male   18
```

First will work as long as there is only one unique value in the columns where you want to 'preserve' the value. Otherwise implement mode to keep the most common value, or 'unique' to get a list of all values.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can do that using `pandas aggregate sum`

like

```
df.groupby(['user_id'])[["points"]].sum()

df.groupby(['user_id'])[["list_of_attribute"]].sum()
```

And its also possible to pass multiple `columns` in `list_of_attributes`
but that would have to `subset` of columns otherwise `KeyError`.